# Curl post data and headers only

Tags: curl

I want to get the headers only from a curl request

`curl -I www.google.com`

All grand. Now I want to do that but to pass in post data too:

`curl -I -d'test=test' www.google.com`

But all I get is:

`Warning: You can only select one HTTP request!`

Anyone have any idea how to do this or am I doing something stupid?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The `-I` option tells curl to do a HEAD request while the `-d'test=test'` option tells curl to do a POST, so you're telling curl to do two different request types.

```
curl -s -d'test=test' -D- -o/dev/null www.google.com
```

or, on Windows:

```
curl -s -d'test=test' -D- -onul: www.google.com
```

That is the neatest way to do this as far as I can find.  The options are:

- `-D-` Dump the header to the file listed, or stdout when `-` is passed, like this.
- `-o/dev/null` Send the body to the file listed.  Here, we discard the body so we only see the headers.
- `-s` Silent (no progress bar)

Comment: An explanation of what the flags mean would be helpful

Comment: **-s**: silent (no progress-bar)

**-d <data>**: performs a POST with the given query-string 
**-D <file>**: dump-header to file (stdout when - is passed)
**-o <file>**: output response to file

The manual cites all these flags anyway.

Comment: If someone wants to run this on Windows just replace `-o/dev/null` with `-o nul` (tested in Windows XP).

Answer (score 30):

`-d` means you are sending form data, via the `POST` method. `-I` means you are just peeking at the metadata via `HEAD`.

I'd suggest either

- Download to `/dev/null` and write the headers via the `-D headerfile` to the file `headerfile`
- Use `-i` to include the headers in the answers and skip everything from the first empty line.

Comment: Old, I know, but I would suggest adding `-s` to clean up the output a little bit.

Comment: Wow, yeah `-i` is exactly what I think everyone is looking for. Why are the other answers more complicated? I'm sure there's some nuances here.