# PHP - Debugging Curl

Tags: php, debugging, curl

I'd like to see what the post fields in the request are before I send it. (For debugging purposes).

The PHP library (class) I am using is already made (not by me), so I am trying to understand it.

As far as I can tell, it uses `curl_setopt()` to set different options like headers and such and then it uses `curl_exec()` to send the request.

Ideas on how to see what post fields are being sent?

Comment: See also [How to display request headers with command line curl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252851/how-to-display-request-headers-with-command-line-curl).

Answer (score 195, accepted):

You can enable the `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` option:

```
curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
```

When `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` is set, output is written to **STDERR** or the file specified using `CURLOPT_STDERR`. The output is very informative.

You can also use tcpdump or wireshark to watch the network traffic.

Comment: It is worth noting that this will not work if you have set `CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT` to `TRUE`.  So far as I can tell...

Comment: Than work $info = curl_getinfo($curlhandle); - This comment for myself)

Comment: tcpdump/wireshark ftw.

Answer (score 484):

You can enable the `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` option <sup>[Curl](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_VERBOSE.html), [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)</sup> and log that information to a (temporary) `CURLOPT_STDERR`:

```
// CURLOPT_VERBOSE: TRUE to output verbose information.
// Writes output to STDERR, 
// -or- the file specified using CURLOPT_STDERR.
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

$streamVerboseHandle = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_STDERR, $streamVerboseHandle);
```

You can then read it after curl has done the request:

```
$result = curl_exec($curlHandle);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    printf("cUrl error (#%d): %s<br>\n",
           curl_errno($curlHandle),
           htmlspecialchars(curl_error($curlHandle)))
           ;
}

rewind($streamVerboseHandle);
$verboseLog = stream_get_contents($streamVerboseHandle);

echo "cUrl verbose information:\n", 
     "<pre>", htmlspecialchars($verboseLog), "</pre>\n";
```

(I originally [answered similar but more extended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9571305/367456) in a related question.)

More information like metrics about the last request is available via [`curl_getinfo`](http://php.net/curl_getinfo). This information can be useful for debugging curl requests, too. A usage example, I would normally wrap that into a function:

```
$version = curl_version();
extract(curl_getinfo($curlHandle));
$metrics = <<<EOD
URL....: $url
Code...: $http_code ($redirect_count redirect(s) in $redirect_time secs)
Content: $content_type Size: $download_content_length (Own: $size_download) Filetime: $filetime
Time...: $total_time Start @ $starttransfer_time (DNS: $namelookup_time Connect: $connect_time Request: $pretransfer_time)
Speed..: Down: $speed_download (avg.) Up: $speed_upload (avg.)
Curl...: v{$version['version']}
EOD;
```

Comment: fopen option should be 'w+'

Comment: @iisisrael: You are right. Corrected. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Before you jump into debugging, however: Try checking the apache log in case an error was tossed (like curl php not being installed, so the function failed!)

Comment: Thank you. Unluckily, it does not log all the content of the a POST, as `curl -v` does.

Comment: @MarcoSulla: This is perhaps a different curl version? Compare `curl --version` and `php -i | grep -i curl`.

Answer (score 76):

Here is a simpler code for the same:

```
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);
```

where $fp is a file handle to output errors. For example:

```
   $fp = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/errorlog.txt', 'w');
```

( Read on http://curl.haxx.se/mail/curlphp-2008-03/0064.html )

Comment: I would have liked to use the answer of @Michaël-R- but I didnt get verbose in the PHP log. Logging to a new file like this worked tho.

Answer (score 33):

Here is an even simplier way, by writing directly to php error output

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen('php://stderr', 'w'));
```

Answer (score 31):

To just get the info of a CURL request do this:

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
var_dump($info);
```

Comment: For "after" response the curl_getinfo its excelent but for malformed urls for example the getinfo returns non info, the opt CURLOPT_VERBOSE its a better for example

Answer (score 10):

If you just want a very quick way to debug the result:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_exec($ch);
$curl_error = curl_error($ch);
echo "<script>console.log($curl_error);</script>"
```

Answer (score 4):

Output debug info to STDERR:

```
$curlHandler = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curlHandler, [
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://postman-echo.com/get?foo=bar',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,

    /**
     * Specify debug option
     */
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
]);

curl_exec($curlHandler);

curl_close($curlHandler);
```

Output debug info to file:

```
$curlHandler = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curlHandler, [
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://postman-echo.com/get?foo=bar',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,

    /**
     * Specify debug option.
     */
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,

    /**
     * Specify log file.
     * Make sure that the folder is writable.
     */
    CURLOPT_STDERR => fopen('./curl.log', 'w+'),
]);

curl_exec($curlHandler);

curl_close($curlHandler);
```

See https://github.com/andriichuk/php-curl-cookbook#debug-request

Answer (score 1):

Another (crude) option is to utilize netcat for dumping the full request:

```
nc -l -p 8000 -w 3 | tee curldbg.txt
```

And of course sending the failing request to it:

```
curl_setup(CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/testytest");
```

Notably that will always hang+fail, since netcat won't ever construct a valid HTTP response. It's really just for inspecting what really got sent. The better option, of course, is using a [http request debugging service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725430/http-test-server-accepting-get-post-requests).