# curl fails sometimes in concurrent Github action builds

Tags: curl, github-actions

I have set up a Github action pipeline that builds and tests the software in the repo using different configurations and platforms. All of these builds make use of curl to download dependencies and two of the builds run on windows. In these two windows builds, curl fails sometimes, but not always.

Here is the curl command:

https://github.com/DLR-SC/tigl/blob/608985554f5a4a505b96a0dc99a3843a2e7072f1/.github/workflows/build-test-deploy.yml#L138

And here is the log of a failed run:

https://github.com/DLR-SC/tigl/runs/921000612?check_suite_focus=true#step:8:27

Does anyone have an idea what could cause this behavior or how I could debug something like this? Are the windows builds interfering with each other?

Comment: Can you try to use verbose to display the response header for curl? Maybe there is a rate limit in place or something
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26644485/8782778

Comment: I added `--verbose`, but the output in the Github action log has about the same level of verbosity as before: https://github.com/DLR-SC/tigl/runs/922247082?check_suite_focus=true#step:8:31 :)

Comment: Some other people (including myself) also encounter some network issues from time to time. See https://github.community/t/ubuntu-runners-regulary-fail-while-installing-dependency-packages/18058