# why curl cannot display http header by using option -i

Tags: shell, curl

I use curl tool to get something within http protocol, and intent to use option -i to display http-header. There's output message without http-header, only http-body from server in the terminal.

[image: the error]

Answer (score 0):

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252851/how-to-display-request-headers-with-command-line-curl), you can try `---verbose` option instead of `-i`

As the comment by cfeduke in the question mentioned, it depends on the response of the server as well.