# curl -D- option

Tags: bash, curl

I was reading the JIRA REST API tutorial and in their example curl request, they show

```
curl -D- -u username:password <rest-of-request>
```

What is the `-D-` syntax with the dash before and after?

Comment: See [Curl post data and headers only](http://stackoverflow.com/a/287299/1983854) : `-D- Dump the header to the file listed, or stdout when - is passed`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To quote `man curl`:

> ```
>   -D, --dump-header <file>
>           Write the protocol headers to the specified file.
>
>           This  option is handy to use when you want to store
>           the headers that a HTTP site sends to you. C
> ```

After a `-D` you normally give the *name of the file* where you want to dump the headers. As with many utilities, `-` is recognized as [an alias to *stdout*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3797806/2363712). 
<sub>(if you're not familiar with that concept: when you launch the command from a terminal without redirection, *stdout* is the "terminal screen")</sub>

The `-D-` (without space) form is exactly the same as `-D -` (or on Linux at least, `-D /dev/stdout`)

Comment: Interesting! I see this interesting and related post: [Does “ - ” mean stdout in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3797795/1983854)